# LVGL GUI example won't run

Tags: c, macos, user-interface

I've been trying to figure this out for days. I am running the LVGL example configured for Eclipse CDT on my Mac. I installed SDL2 and Eclipse CDT. I put the downloaded project folder to eclipse-workspace. Then I enter Eclipse to build the project. Errors all over the place. I followed few tutorial to change settings for binary parser and toolchain. Now I got one last error saying "fatal error:lvgl/lvgl.h" file not found. The thing is lvgl.h file is right under the lvgl directory. Can someone help me with this issue? I really want to set up my PC simulator for LVGL development. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue:
<strike>To fix it I went to Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings, then under "Cross G++ Compiler" and "Cross GCC Compiler" I clicked on "Includes" and manually added the directory "${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}}"</strike>

Ok that did only partly solve it. I finally solved it as follows:

**Be sure to import the LVGL example as general project not C/C++ project!**

So Import -> General -> "Existing project into Workspace"
Browse to the lv_sim_eclipse_sdl folder and click finish.

The project should now build without issues.

After that, to run it you need to add a run configuration.
Point it to "lv_sim_eclipse_sdl/Debug/lv_sim_eclipse_sdl", click run and the example should run.